# CASE WHEN IN ({set of numbers})

Tags: mysql

I need a following case statement in MySQL.

When column value is (1, 2, 5, 7, 14, 17) - return 0, otherwise return 1 and I need to use it in order by clause.

My first impression was to make query like this:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY (CASE column WHEN IN (1, 2, 5, 7, 14, 17) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) DESC
```

but this obviously fails.

I can write it like this:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY (CASE column WHEN 1 THEN WHEN 2 THEN 0 WHEN 5 THEN ... 0 ELSE 1 END) DESC
```

But I am looking for a more elegant way. Is there any other elegant syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to work

```
SELECT ... 
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN (column IN (1, 2, 5, 7, 14, 17) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) DESC
```

---

Demonstration:

> ```
> with cte0 as 
> (
>   select 120 x from dual union
>   select 1 from dual union
>   select 22 from dual union
>   select 7 from dual
> )
> select * from cte0
> order by (case when x in (22) then 0 else 1 end) desc;
> ```
>
> ```
> |   X |
> | --: |
> |   1 |
> | 120 |
> |   7 |
> |  22 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a2f67867df2f25c7516102f3d75f0924)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nested query`, e.g.:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM (
    SELECT A, CASE WHEN B IN (1, 2, 5, 7, 14, 17) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ORDERING
    FROM TABLE
) B
ORDER BY B.ORDERING DESC;
```